# Characterising the set of parameters that satisfy a system of non-linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I am looking for a solution to the following problem and could not find an answer so far. I have a quintic equation, $f(x;a,b,c,\cdots)-x=0$, where $x$ is the variable with respect to which I need the equation to be solved, and $a,b,c,\ldots$ are parameters whose values satisfy certain restrictions (they are all positive, and some of them can only take values between $0$ and $1$). I am looking for a way to numerically characterise the set of parameters $a,b,c,\ldots$ for which *(i)* the quintic is solved and *(ii)* at the solution, ensure that the derivative of the quintic satisfies the following condition:
\begin{gather}
f'(x;a,b,c,\cdots)-1\approx \epsilon,
\end{gather}
for $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small. 
Is there an efficient (i.e., not too time-consuming) way of doing this in Mathematica? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the family of parameters with `Reduce`. For example

```
f[x_] := x^5 + a x^4 + b

N@Reduce[f[x] == x && f'[x] == 1 && 0 < a < 1, {x, a, b}, Reals]
```

[image]

Here `x` acts as an arbitrary parameter with certain restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is exactly what I was looking for. I have noticed that evaluating numerically `Reduce` may require to set a high level of digit precision. This was the case in my problem, at least.